# ggplot with variables different columns in dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

| landtype | O3 | PM10 | PM2.5 | Month_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| urban | 40 | 27 | 50 | January |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | January |
| urban | 50 | 29 | 50 | February |
| rural | 20 | 25 | 40 | February |
| urban | 40 | 25 | 50 | March |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | March |
| urban | 60 | 25 | 50 | April |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | April |
| urban | 70 | 27 | 50 | May |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | May |
| urban | 40 | 27 | 50 | June |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | June |
| urban | 40 | 27 | 50 | July |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | July |
| urban | 40 | 27 | 50 | August |
| rural | 30 | 25 | 40 | August |

Now I would like to create a histogram which shows the contrast between urban and rural and all the values 03,PM10 and PM2.5 for Months.

I used that  code

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month_name, y = O3,PM10,PM2.5, fill = O3,PM10,PM2.5)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~landtype)  + ggtitle("air pollution contrast between city and countryside")
```

BUt it is not what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to reshape to long first to do this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data  |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
   -c(landtype, Month_name), 
   names_to = "pollution_type"
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    month_short = substr(Month_name, 1, 3)
  )  |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = month_short, 
    y = value, 
    fill = landtype)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("air pollution contrast between city and countryside") +
  facet_wrap(vars(pollution_type)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60), 
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  ylab("μg")
```

[image]